# How to find data being stored as bin data via MongoBinData() function?

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a problem when I use the MongoDB

When I directly store a string into the MongoDB, it would cause an error:

> non-utf8 string: fran��ai

But I don't want to encode the string into UTF-8, so I use the **MongoBinData()** to do this, now data can be stored into the MongoDB.

But when I want to find/search something in the database it returns nothing

My find method is

```
find(array("lines" =>array("bin"=> new MongoRegex("/1234/i"))));
```

and returns NULL (The database has many string containing "1234")

Could you give me some advice ?

Comment: Regex does not work with bin data, why don't you want to encode to utf8?

Comment: Ok, thank you for your advice. But if all the data has to be converted to utf-8 for regex search, it's not very convenient and something could not be done.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expression only work on UTF-8 encoded strings. So you have to convert the strings to UTF-8 to make them search-able. When you insist on keeping your character encoding for whatever reason, your only other option is to have two fields for every string, one with the utf8-represenation and one with the BinData-representation in your own encoding.

Comment: Thanks for your advice and I'm sorry for so late to see your answer.

Comment: Thanks for your advice and i want to know: if data was saved as binary data, can i use keyword to search ?

Comment: @CruzerZero BinData doesn't support regular expressions or text search. All you can search for is exact equality with the whole field-content or use a javascript-based search with $where (very slow). Maybe $gt and $lt work, but I am not sure about that or how they behave. One option would be to extract an array of some relevant keywords from the binary data and store them as text in another field. That way you could even create an index.

Comment: Thank you for your patience to answer my question. And i hava to try another database to do my job. Thank you again!